# NServiceBus purge audit queue

Tags: nservicebus, serviceinsight

I have multiple NSB endpoints using MSMQ as transport and pointing to centralized audit queue.

ServiceControl forwards the messages from the audit queue to its RavenDb and ServiceInsight/ServicePulse show those messages.

Over a period, I'm seeing the audit queue is filled up with lot of messages which is becoming a maintenance issue.

Question - Is there any configuration in ServiceControl that can purge the messages in the audit queue automatically?

Comment: Do you mean the audit.log queue in MSMQ that ServiceControl can be configured to copy the messages into as described here: http://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/errorlog-auditlog-behavior

Answer (score 2):

ServiceControl comes with message retention policies that you can also customize. You didn't mention which version of ServiceControl you're using but the latest one comes with default expiration of messages after 30 days. It is all documented [here](http://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/how-purge-expired-data).